# Cannot convert IQueryable<IEnumerable<string>> to return type IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

In the following function I get an error when I try to return a value saying:

> Cannot convert
>   `System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>`
>   to return type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetModuleKindPropertyNames(long moduleKindId)
{
    var configurationId = GetModuleKindPertypeConfigurationId(moduleKindId);
    var propertyNames = _dbSis.ModuleKinds
                              .Where(t => t.PerTypeConfigurationId == configurationId)
                              .Select(x => x.PerTypeConfiguration.Properties
                              .Select(z => z.Name));

    return propertyNames; //red line below property names
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to select items from *a collection within a collection* and *flatten* the result into a single sequence.

Conceptually, something like:

[image: Example class diagram]

If that's the case, you're looking for the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method:

```
var propertyNames = _dbSis.ModuleKinds
                          .Where(t => t.PerTypeConfigurationId == configurationId)
                          .SelectMany(x => x.PerTypeConfiguration.Properties)
                          .Select(z => z.Name);
```

Comment: Basically ModuleKind has `long? PertypeConfigurationId` and `public PropertyConfigurationDefinition PerTypeConfiguration{ get; set; }`, and PropertyConfigurationDefinition has  public `ICollection<Property> Properties
        {
            get { return _properties; }
            set { _properties = value; }
        }` and Finally Property has `public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: will try what you said and will get back